# How to calculate the second derivative of this example?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate the second derivative of the following equation:

$$f(x)=\frac{6}{(x^2+3)}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{-12x}{(x^2+3)^2}$$

The correct answer given was $$f''(x) = \frac{36(x+1)(x-1)}{(x^2+3)^3}$$ but the second derivative that I have gotten was different from the answer.

I have shown the calculations below and would like to understand where is the mistake. Would anyone be able to point out my mistake?

$$f'(x) =\frac{-12x}{(x^2+3)^2} = (-12x)(x^2+3)^{-2}$$

$$= (-12x)\frac{d}{dx} [(x^2+3)^{-2}]+(x^2+3)^{-2}\frac{d}{dx}[-12x]$$

$$=         48x^2(x^2+3)^{-3} -12(x^2+3)^{-2}$$

Comment: Those answers [coincide](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+48x%5E2%2F%28x%5E2%2B3%29%5E3-12%2F%28x%5E2%2B3%29%5E2)

Comment: Those are numerically the same: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r9v4dz8aly

Comment: It happens a lot in calculus.  Two answers are the same, but look very different.  So you should have some strategies for testing this.  First, pick a couple values for $x$ and plug them into both expressions to see if you get the same value.   Then maybe graph both expressions.

Comment: @B.Goddard would this be an acceptable answer given that it is a different expression or it is not "simplified" enough? ps i am learning calculus on my own.

Comment: @ilovetolearn  It would depend on the professor.  I think most wouldn't care to much about the final form.  But note that eventually you want to _use_ the second derivative and it will be easier to find the roots using the book's form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep going...

$$48x^2(x^2+3)^{-3}-12(x^2+3)^{-2}$$

$$=\frac{48x^2}{(x^2+3)^3}-\frac{12}{(x^2+3)^2}$$

$$=\frac{48x^2-12(x^2+3)}{(x^2+3)^3}$$

$$=\frac{36x^2-36}{(x^2+3)^3}$$

Factorise the numerator to match the given answer.